# Datatables filterColumn doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

Having this code:

```php
$campaigns = CampaignMembers::with(['company', 'note'])
    ->select(['*', DB::raw('count(*) as count')])
    ->where('campaign_id', $campaign_id)
    ->havingRaw('count = ?', [42])
    ->groupBy('customer_id');

return DataTables::of($campaigns)
    ->filterColumn('count', function($q, $kw) {           
       $q->select(['*', DB::raw('count(*) as count')])
           ->where('campaign_id', 8)
           ->havingRaw('count = ?', [42])
           ->groupBy('customer_id');         
    })               
    ->addColumn('show', '<a href="/showCampaignCompany/{{$customer_id}}"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>')  
    ->addColumn('edit', '<a href="/editCustomer/{{$id}}"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>')
    ->addColumn('delete', '<a href="#" data-id="{{$id}}" class="deleteTemplate"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>')                     
    ->rawColumns(['show', 'edit', 'delete']) 
    ->make(true);
```

Trying to make a `count(*)` result searchable, I have added a call to `filterColumn()` in order to perform that custom search since searching in an alias column is not supported. The problem is that it looks like that the `filterColumn()` result is simply ignored. Since I have hardcoded the count value, I expected to receive the same results all the time. But I instead receive new. filtered results. What do I miss?

Using the latest yajra datatables 9.19

Edit for some relationship info:

The CampaignMembers model has a customer_id. The customer table can be either a company or a physical person. It is not really important to talk about relationships since I group everything using customer_id that is a "local" column even if later, I fetch the name of the company or person through a relationship. The count is derived from the the CampaignMembers table. It counts how many times, the same customer_id is found. Simple.

Comment: What are you trying to count? You have a `$campaign_id` variable, so you are pulling all the members of that campaign, and `count(*)` will tell you how many there are. So you want to get no results unless the count is exactly equal to 42 or whatever?

Comment: I count how many CampaignMembers each company has. The group by, groups the members results with each company name and i can get the name through the relationship. This example returns just 1 company which has 42 members. But when I type a number like 4 or 42 in the search box, then no results are shown. No errors either.

Comment: I think it might be helpful for you to include some information on the relationships between these models, and what data you expect to get from this query. Are you just looking for counts? Because you lose all the information on the `CampaignMember` objects by grouping them so there's no point in selecting '*' and eager loading the relationship.

Comment: "This example returns just 1 company which has 42 members" but you said the filter is ignored? Is it ignored or is it working?

Comment: The first query in the $campaigns variable has the correct result as excpected. Can I replicate the same by searching? The initial query when loading the page works. But then when invoking the filter, the count is not getting into consideration in the global search

Comment: I will add some relationship info in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after 3 days, I managed to solve it. I concatenated the result into one column to make the table more clear. The solution feels very complicated but it works well. Certainly with a performance penalty:

First I created a custom attribute in the model:

```
protected $appends = ['customer_count'];

public function getCustomerCountAttribute()
{
   return $this->company->name . '(' .$this->where('customer_id', $this->customer_id)->count() . ')';
}
```

The name of the company resides in the relation so I did this in the javascript declaration of the table:

```
{data: 'customer_count', name: 'company.name'},
```

Then, in the controller, the function called by ajax looks like this:

```
$campaigns = CampaignMembers::with(['company', 'note'])
        ->where('campaign_id', $campaign_id)
        ->groupBy('customer_id')
        ->select('campaign_members.*');     
        
return DataTables::of($campaigns)   
->filterColumn('company.name', function($q, $kw) use($campaigns){
      $countIds = $campaigns->get()->filter(function($item) use ($kw) {
      if(Str::contains($item->customer_count, $kw))
         return $item->customer_count;
      })->pluck('id');

      $q->whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($kw) {
                    return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$kw%");
      })->orWhereIn('campaign_members.id', $countIds); 
 })->toJson();
```

This way, even if the search **partialy matches** a count number or the name of the company, both with return results.